# use django template variable works for font color but not for url due to static path tag

Tags: django, templates

I have prepared and Django html template that uses template variables from a databse to overule the standard css of the page. This will allow me to use user specific font colors.

I have it working for the font color, but I get an error on loading a user specic image. See code below:

```
<!-- Logo -->  
{% load static %}
<img class="LogoPos img-responsive"
        src="{% static 'img/{{ClubSettingsApplied.0.logo_image}}' %}"
        alt="Generic logo image"
        title="Client logo">
</img>
<!-- Font color -->

<style>
th { 
font-weight: bold; 
color: #{{ClubSettingsApplied.0.font_color}};
padding-left: 0.2em;
}  

</style>
```

The use of template variables does not seem to work togehter with the static path tag.

Off course I can build up the complete url including the path from my view... However perhaps there is a smarter work around.

Looking forward to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The static template tag only accept a string as argument and it can't render another variable inside that string.

The solution is to use [get_static_prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-get_static_prefix) template tag. It will help you in this case by rendering the correct prefix that you need to resolve the static file.

I tested this on django 1.7 and django docs state it should work the same way as far back as 1.4 or even further.

```
<!-- Logo -->  
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}

<img class="LogoPos img-responsive"
     src="{{ STATIC_PREFIX }}img/{{ClubSettingsApplied.0.logo_image}}"
     alt="Generic logo image"
     title="Client logo">
</img>

<!-- Font color -->
<style>
th { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #{{ClubSettingsApplied.0.font_color}};
    padding-left: 0.2em;
}  
</style>
```